# Reshape table using column values as column names?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, reshape

I am trying to reshape a table. The below table was created from using this code on a df:

```
df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(Organization, Year) %>% 
    tally()
```

| Organization | Year | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 1999 | 3 |
| X | 2010 | 3 |
| Y | 2009 | 4 |
| Y | 2010 | 5 |
| Y | 2011 | 5 |
| Z | 2008 | 5 |
| Z | 2011 | 5 |

What I'm trying to create:

| Organization | 1999 | 2008 | 2009 | 2010 | 2011 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| Y | 0 | 0 | 4 | 5 | 5 |
| Z | 0 | 5 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

Where it will only take the existing years and not create new years in-between (like the gap between 1999 and 2008) and it will fill in 0's as needed.

Comment: directly do `table(df[c('Organization', 'Year')])` instead of groupby, then tally then pivot_wider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `pivot_wider` after `arrange`ing the rows by 'Year'.  With `pivot_wider`, it uses the same order of occurrence of data

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
     arrange(Year) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = Year, values_from = N, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
  Organization `1999` `2008` `2009` `2010` `2011`
  <chr>         <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
1 X                 3      0      0      3      0
2 Z                 0      5      0      0      5
3 Y                 0      0      4      5      5
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Organization = c("X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Z", 
"Z"), Year = c(1999L, 2010L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 2008L, 2011L
), N = c(3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: wow thank you! This worked perfectly. Except the years are in random order. Is there a way to sort them numerically so it goes from 1999 to 2011?

Comment: sorry! Did not know about this, I see the "arrange(Year)", problem solved, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the function `dcast` in the `data.table` as follows:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(as.data.table(df), Organization ~ Year, value.var="N", fill=0)

#    Organization  1999  2008  2009  2010  2011
# 1:            X     3     0     0     3     0
# 2:            Y     0     0     4     5     5
# 3:            Z     0     5     0     0     5
```